Best Practices for using middleware in ASP.NET Core Web API for exception handling, authentication, and error logging
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API project and I am trying to implement some global functionalities using middleware. Specifically, I want to handle the following:

Global exception handling: catching unhandled exceptions and returning standardized error responses.
Authentication: ensuring all requests are authenticated before processing.
Global error logging: logging all errors that occur during the request processing pipeline.

My questions are:

Is it a recommended practice to use middleware for global exception handling in ASP.NET Core Web API? If so, are there any specific patterns or libraries that are commonly used?
Is middleware the best approach for implementing authentication, or should this be handled differently?
For global error logging, is middleware a suitable solution, or are there other preferred methods or tools for this purpose?

Here's a brief overview of my current implementation:
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exception and return response
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }
    
    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        // Log exception and set response status code
        // Return standardized error response
    }
}

// In Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
  
    // Other middleware registrations
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}


Actually asp.net core contains this exception handler, you could directly use it , called UseExceptionHandler.

Middleware is a powerful tool for implementing global functionalities like exception handling, authentication, and error logging.

Global Exception Handling: Using middleware for global exception handling is a recommended practice. It can catch unhandled exceptions that occur in the pipeline and return standardized error responses.ASP.NET Core has built-in middleware for handling exceptions: UseExceptionHandler and UseDeveloperExceptionPage. Custom middleware for exception handling can also be created. Libraries like Serilog, NLog, or others can be used for advanced logging and exception management.
Example already exists in your code sample.

Authentication: While middleware can handle some aspects of authentication, ASP.NET Core provides a more structured approach using authentication and authorization middleware: UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization. These built-in middlewares should be used to handle authentication and authorization. Example already exists in your code sample.

Global Error Logging: Middleware is suitable for logging errors that occur during request processing. For comprehensive logging, including logs outside the request pipeline (e.g., background tasks), you should also configure logging services. For logging your Sample code can look like:
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
private readonly ILogger _logger;
 public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger)
 {
     _next = next;
     _logger = logger;
 }

 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
 {
     try
     {
         await _next(context);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _logger.LogError(ex, "An unhandled exception occurred.");
         await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
     }
 }

 private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
 {
     context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
     context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

     var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = exception.Message });
     return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
 }

}
// In Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
app.UseMiddleware();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllers();
});
}


As Exception Handling, Logging, Authentication are activities that are spread across entire application, and are used by all modules rather than adding code in every class for these modules, we can create middlewares and inject then where required.
